# C# Trouble getting Average and Total correct (Connected a access database up to a Student form)

Tags: c#, ms-access

The problem I'm  having is the average is showing to many decimal places I only want two decimal places and the total is showing the total number of rows

**heres my code for the Average:**

```
    private void lblAverage_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        decimal av = 0.0m;

        for (int i = 0; i < resultsDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            string temp = resultsDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

            av += decimal.Parse(temp);

            if (decimal.Parse(temp) >= 50)
            {
                resultsDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }

            if (decimal.Parse(temp) < 50)
            {
                resultsDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }

        av = av / resultsDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1;

        lblAverage.Text = "Average: " + av.ToString();
    }
```

**heres my code for the Total:**

```
    private void lblTotal_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        decimal Total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < resultsDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Total += Convert.ToDecimal(resultsDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
        }

        lblTotal.Text = "Total: " + Total.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a format string into the `ToString()` call.

For example, you can:

```
var number = 987.654321M;
var textNumber1 = number.ToString(); //Generates the string 987.654321
var textNumber2 = number.ToString("#0.00"); //Generates the string 987.65
```

Please note that using format string rounds the number. Given the input number `987.674` the format string `#0.0` will produce `987.7`, but the format string `#0.00` will produce `987.67`.

You can calso check in the MSDN for more details on the format strings for numbers:

[Custom Numeric String Formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for that. I Have now fixed the average but I still need to figure out the total. Im thinking it might have to do with the cell.

Comment: I've noticed that for the average you're using `resultsDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[3]`, but for the total you're using `resultsDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1]`. Notice the different index `1` and `3` for both cases. Maybe that is the issue?

Comment: Also, why for the average your for is defined as `for (int i = 0; i < resultsDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1; i++)`? The last row on the grid doesn't have a valid number to accumulate? The same goes for `av = av / resultsDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1;`, its performing an average that doesn't respect the real total of rows in the grid.